# Oracle ODBC read fails with left join

Tags: sql, database, oracle, left-join

I have a small Problem but its annoying me  extremly.
i want to left join a table  but i get only the error that the odbc read fails.
When i comment out the left join block the query works.

im pretty sure that theres no typo and im frustated..

any ideas?

```
select 
*
from
SYSADM.KATARTIKEL

left join SYSADM.TBLFALL
on SYSADM.KATARTIKEL.ITBROWID = SYSADM.TBLFALL.ITBROWID

where rownum <= 150;
```

heres the error 
its in german..

```
Fehler beim Lesen über ODBC
select 
*
from
SYSADM.KATARTIKEL

left join SYSADM.TBLFALL
on SYSADM.KATARTIKEL.ITBROWID = SYSADM.TBLFALL.ITBROWID

where rownum <= 150
```

EDIT: The Solotion for this case is to create aliases:

```
select 
    K.*,

    T.ITBROWID as ITID
from
    SYSADM.KATARTIKEL K

left join SYSADM.TBLFALL T
on K.ITBROWID = T.ITBROWID

where 
    rownum <= 150;
```

EDIT: The problem is select * you cant select anything and doing a join afterwards!

Comment: could you please post your error

Comment: Please, provide error's text (and stack trace if it is an exception)

Comment: `try select 1 from ...`: lets return good old `1` instead of `*` and nothing more. Do you still have the error?

Comment: with the 1 i dont get the error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious issue is that you have duplicate column names.  I would advise you to list all the columns explicitly, but you can take this shortcut:

```
select k.*, f.col1, f.col2
from SYSADM.KATARTIKEL k left join
     SYSADM.TBLFALL f
     on k.ITBROWID = f.ITBROWID
where rownum <= 150;
```

Of course, you might have other issues, such as `SYSADM.TBLFALL` not existing or `ITBROWID` not being in both tables.

Note that I also introduced table aliases.  I strongly advise you to use table aliases and qualified column names in all your queries.

Comment: for what do i need the col1 and col2 ?

Comment: What columns did you need from TBLFALL?

Comment: At the Moment just the ITBROWID

Comment: Then I suggest using `SELECT k.*, f.ITBROWID AS TBLFALL_ITBROWID`. That at least will eliminate the duplicate column name issue.

Comment: worked! thanks! 
i have an idea now and try to do it with the left join